# How to sets the target of another project

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ipod

In my project i integrate the RESTkit in my application for that i follow below post url

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/

In that one screen given for the sets the target of another application.

but in that this tutorial made into the xcode 3 while i use the xcode 4.3.1,

**So My question is how to set the target of the another application in our project for that what to do**

Below image shows the sets the target of a application in xcode3 then how to sets taget into xcode4.

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found the Problem after Some R&D.

followings are the steps to Add the target into xcode 4.3.1

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]